# How to dynamically instantiating an class referring othere classes

Tags: java, instantiation

I have write an classLoader. By using it I dynamically instantiating an class. But if the class refers to other classes, I got error saying that can not find the symbol although I have  already included these other classes in the classpath. I can I solve this.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String className = "classLoader.SayHello";
        String Dir = "D:\\temp\\";
        KonaClassLoader kcl = new KonaClassLoader();
        Class<?> clazz = null;
        Object obj = null;
        Method m = null;
        try {           
            clazz = kcl.loadClassFromLocal(Dir,className);          

            obj = clazz.newInstance();
            m = clazz.getMethod("sayGoodbye", String.class);

            m.invoke(obj, "Robin");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

The problem is that if I define any other object in the class SayHello, I got error saying that "can not find Symbol".I have  already included these other classes in the classpath.

Comment: Do you mean you can't use other classes that were defined in the JRE, in the classpath, or in D:\temp? You might need to make KonaClassLoader decorate the classloader of the main class and try loading classes with it after loading from Dir fails.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but I think this tutorial might be of use for you: http://www.javablogging.com/java-classloader-2-write-your-own-classloader/.

Comment: Can you post code of KonaClassLoader ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When compiling SayHello, the class path should hold the library of the class contained in Say Hello Class.
2. When we execute KonaClassLoader will try to load SayHello and then load the contained class.

No need to write loadclassfromfile method we can use existing method loadClass and just mention the library in Java class path. I executed the same and ran through successfully.

D:\Kepler Projects\FirstStep\target\classes\com\firststep\classloader>java -cp "
D:\Kepler Projects\FirstStep\target\classes;D:\Temp" com.firststep.classloader.C
lient
say good bye Robin